# Time-Aware Layer from ArcGIS Pro is not working in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, time

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.1 to share a web map with time aware layer on AGOL.  When I publish the web map I get no errors but the field for time is missing when I open the map online.  The time slider appears but no features appear even though they are in the table.

The [layer](https://services4.arcgis.com/IUzqjgr4am7zKbNO/arcgis/rest/services/Waffle_House_Locations_since_1962_WFL1/FeatureServer/0?token=R_8PRCErq6J0Y2lIdWTvOAdrIxGE2-MXuVebaSBHRefjASLfCAqbQBVJ3s505Al6kd001SKQ4K90lHC8lQ114Mhq-bJocBZDxm4GMy8nKVMeBVMPfpkex2cyaruW8aFQ1hIcHYbzGI65KsdXk2fj3rlUzHPW7XKP-i_YaD_om2VLhcKKnR6Km84fg0v6VsfRK5klZBd6gsvJDhECd7Po7W5M6DbWa_vfcp_1DPM5rKc.) contains 1,905 features with a Date field.  In the service there is a field for "USER_DATEOPEN" but that is a Long Type which I converted to Date.  That new field is missing.

Comment: Care to share the new layer with the converted date as a geopackage or  fGDB and can test from our end

Comment: Are you asking me to publish a package?

Comment: Yes, a sample of your data would be nice, so that we could try to recreate your problem, on a different system and try to find a solution for that.

Comment: A shapefile with the original data is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17ZMPvsDTaN0hfyYyTcLdoWf6cLk7KUPs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this works in ArcGIS Pro, but within ArcMap you could go into the settings of the layer before publishing, enable time and map your time field, set your time interval, and also set Time Zones etc. Within ArcGIS Online, enable the time and make sure your hours match up. Whenever I had something happen like you described it was usually time zones for me.

Comment: I enabled time in ArcGIS Pro.  It works fine on that layer in that environment.  The problem is that the field associated with time is not present in the published layer online.